WAMP Server and Laravel public link to storage on NAS
I have been trying for days now to figure out how to make the symbolic storage link in the Laravel public folder access files on my NAS under WAMPServer.
I have a VueJS frontend running separately in a VSCode terminal (for hot reload) and WAMPServer is running my Laravel API backend but both are on the same machine.
I have created a custom link to the NAS as an admin using the following command:

mklink /D "storage" "<path to NAS>"

This WILL work if I launch Laravel using php artisan serve within a VSCode terminal.
However, when I try my WAMP server running as admin it will not. I have the NAS drive mapped. I can see it is being mapped correctly using net use. I can click on the symbolic link in Explorer and it will take me to the correct directory.
I have looked at the permissions of Apache and it is being run as a "LocalSystem Account" which appears to have enough permissions. I have tried changing the LogOn account for the service to my admin account but that doesn't work. I have looked at the permissions of the folder on the NAS and it is "777"
There is obviously something that allows the Laravel php server to access the NAS correctly that I am missing on the WAMP server but I am at a loss to what that could be.
Just as some additional information, I can get WAMPServer to work if I create a link to another directory on the same drive, just not the NAS.
If anyone could suggest a solution, I would appreciate it.
SPECS:
OS: Windows 11
NAS: SMB/1.0CIFS
Laravel: 10
Apache: 2.4.58
PHP: 8.2.13


I spent several hours making storage link work.  Try ln -s path_from_public_to_sourcedir ./storage in your public directory

Thanks for the reply. Sorry, I am not exactly clear on what you are suggesting. The equivalent Windows command for ls is mklink. If I have my storage folder as \NAS\Folder then running mklink /D "storage" "\NAS\Folder" in the public directory of my source would create a link called "storage" that points to that path. So I am not following how your suggestion is different (not 100% familiar with the ls command)

Obviously you're right to use mklink, I was on different OS. What it was in my case, the path pointing to original storage was absolute (meaning starting with / , from root directory) and this wasn't working, even though the absolute path was accurate. I had to use command "storage" "../NAS/Folder". Second argument is now relative path, from /public .
